# LR test for overlapping return data using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, markov-process, likelihood-ratio, runs

I wish to test a null hypothesis as in Christoffersen (1998) to see whether a sequence of Value-at-Risk forecasts $Q_t(p) \in \mathcal{F}_t$ possesses correct conditional coverage. Here $p \in [0,1]$ and $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the information set at time $t$. Let $R_{t+1}$ be the return from period $t$ to $t+1$, then $Q_t(p)$ is efficient if $\mathbb{E}_t(R_{t+1} \le Q_t(p)) = p$.

Let $I_t := 1(R_{t+1} \le Q_t(p))$ and consider the first-order Markov chain for $\{I_t\}$ with transition matrix
$$ \Pi_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 - \pi_{01} & \pi_{01}\\
1 - \pi_{11} & \pi_{11}
\end{pmatrix} $$

Under $H_0$ it follows that $\pi_{01} = \pi_{11}$ and hence a natural test statistic is $S := \hat{\pi}_{11} - \hat{\pi}_{01} $. For example $\hat{\pi}_{11}$ can be estimated by $n_{11}/(n_{10}+n_{11})$, where $n_{11}$ counts the number of times 1 is followed by 1 and $n_{10}$ counts how often 1 is followed by 0.

Bootstrap provides accurate $p$-values for this test if returns are $\textbf{independent}$. However, suppose I consider 30 day returns which are calculated every day. Then returns become highly correlated by construction and I noticed that a bootstrap approach does no longer yield satisfactory results.

Hence my question, is it possible to obtain correct standard errors for the test statistic $S$ by means of some bootstrap procedure?